# Limit outgoing emails in SmarterMail

Tags: email, vps

How can I limit the amount of email sent through my mail server in a given time period. 
After reaching that limit I want to send an email to administrator.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the SmarterMail throttling feature:
https://portal.smartertools.com/kb/a2768/set-up-throttling-for-domains.aspx

That should accomplish what you need or close to it.